# lspci displays wrong VGA compatible Controller

Tags: graphics, radeon, battery, overheating, gpu-driver

I have an HP laptop with an AMD A8-7410 with R5 Graphics (AMD Radeon R5 M330 GPU, can't find drivers for that. AMD Catalyst recognizes this but says `unknown display`). Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. This is what `lspci` shows:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
[AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon APU A4-6000 with R2 Graphics] (rev 45)
```

But the AMD-Catalyst application displays the correct information about the integrated graphics.

The laptop heats up quickly and the fan starts running at full speed, a few minutes after booting up. The battery lasts only for 2 hours. While using windows, I get 4-5 hours.

*How can I fix this?*

Comment: @Priyansh: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/680887/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Comment: I have exactly the same problem here with a Lenovo G40-45. Catalyst displays information only for the iGPU. Seems like AMD has not yet shipped drivers supporting M330, as their driver download page  does not show it as an option.

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem,but when i was running Kali 2.0 from USB, i saw that my integrated graphics was recognized correctly. I think this is because Kali 2.0 runs on an upgraded kernel(Kernel version 4.0). Ive switched to Kali 2.0, the laptop doesn't heat up, even the battery backup has improved a lot(around 5 hours)